# How to use CKEditor plugins in a non npm environment?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have a simple webpage which is using Jquery. I want to use CKEditor 5 and it's Mention plugin feature. I know already that CKEditor 5 has a modular architecture and each plugin has a lot of dependencies so they recommend using npm to resolve all the dependencies but I am not at all using npm and do not want to use it. After some research, I found that I can create a custom build using [online builder](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/) so I went ahead and created my own custom build which has Mention plugin with it. After that, I included mention config while applying ckeditor on my text area as below:

```
ClassicEditor
.create( document.querySelector( '#editor'), {
    toolbar: [ 'heading', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'link', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'blockQuote' ],
    heading: {
        options: [
            { model: 'paragraph', title: 'Paragraph', class: 'ck-heading_paragraph' },
            { model: 'heading1', view: 'h1', title: 'Heading 1', class: 'ck-heading_heading1' },
            { model: 'heading2', view: 'h2', title: 'Heading 2', class: 'ck-heading_heading2' }
        ]
    },

    mention: {
        feeds: [
            {
                marker: '@',
                feed: [ '@Barney', '@Lily', '@Marshall', '@Robin', '@Ted' ],
                minimumCharacters: 1
            }
        ]
    }
} ).then(function(editor){
    window.editor = editor ;
    editor.editing.view.document.on( 'keyup', ( evt, data ) => {
        ChatterFeed.chatterEvents(data,editor);
    } );
})
.catch( error => {
    console.log( error );
} );
```

but this code does not seem to be working and it doesn't do anything when I press @ in the textarea. I am not sure if I am missing something here as I have already spent tons of time to search this with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not working because I was showing this editor in the Bootstrap modal popup and may be due to some css issue, it wasn't working. As soon as I showed it on the main html page, it started working fine.